# Trouble with joins and SUM()

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with retrieving the order quantity minus the received quantity.

The basic version of the tables looks like

```
order_main 
id | status
1  | 2
2  | 1
3  | 3
4  | 2

order_part
id | partid | quantity | status | order_main_id
1  | 12345  | 100      | 2      | 1
2  | 23456  | 20       | 3      | 1
3  | 555    | 15       | 1      | 2
4  | 666    | 10       | 3      | 3
5  | 12345  | 40       | 2      | 4


order_reception
id | order_main_id
1  | 2
2  | 2
3  | 2
4  | 3

order_reception_part
id | partid | quantity | order_reception_id
1  | 12345  | 40       | 1
2  | 23456  | 20       | 1
3  | 12345  | 10       | 2
4  | 12345  | 20       | 3
5  | 666    | 10       | 4
```

So basically I want to know for partid `12345` how many are still in backorder.
The result should look like

```
partid | in_order 
12345  | 70
```

(100 + 40) - (40 + 10 + 20)

The problem with my attempts was that when I tried to SUM the order quantity I got 3*100 one for every reception + 40 because the `order_part` is not directly linked to `order_reception_part`

Extra info status 1 = Ready to order, status 2 = Ordered, 3 = Received

I hope I have explained it well enough for you to understand otherwise please ask me for additional info.

The following query will show what I mean, I need the `SUM()` of `orp.quantity` per order, but the result will show 100 for every reception but I only need '100' 1 time + 80 from the other order.

```
SELECT om.id, op.quantity, orp.quantity
FROM order_main om
JOIN order_part op ON om.id = op.order_main_id
LEFT JOIN order_reception `or` ON om.id = or.order_main_id
LEFT JOIN order_reception_part orp ON or.id = orp.order_reception_id
WHERE op.partid = 12345
AND op.status = 2
```

Comment: TL;DR Just `SUM(DISTINCT your_primary_key_here)`.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing where the +80 is coming from

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry you're right it should be +40

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(quantity) 
    FROM order_part 
    WHERE order_part.partid=12345 - 
    SELECT SUM(quantity) 
    FROM order_reception_part 
    WHERE order_reception_part.partid=12345
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't come up with this, nice and simple solution! thanks

Comment: I've done some tests and this does not always work, because an order can have 50 x part 123 and receives 25 x 123 and the others can't be delivered so this order gets status 4, then in the first SUM the 50 don't get added because status 2 is in order, but in the received parts there are now 25 parts extra. So I really need to link part to part_received via orderid.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer myself. Use joins te get the correct `orp.quantity` and use a subquery to get the overal `op.quantity` and then subtract them.

```
SELECT (
   SELECT SUM(quantity) 
   FROM order_part 
   WHERE partid = p.partid 
   AND `status` = 2
) - IFNULL(SUM(orp.quantity), 0)  

FROM order_main om
JOIN order_part op ON om.id = op.order_main_id
LEFT JOIN order_reception `or` ON om.id = or.order_main_id
LEFT JOIN order_reception_part orp ON or.id = orp.order_reception_id
AND orp.partid = op.partid
WHERE op.partid = p.partid
AND op.status = 2
```